# How can use a js component inside of a vue-vite app using ModuleFederation plugin?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vite, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I've created a component in a js-app and exposes it by modulefederation plugin. The source file of the project is accessible through the following link:
[git-source](https://github.com/amirtbi/vue-js-microfrontend)

The webpack.production.config of js-app is as follows:

```
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const config = {
  mode: "production",

  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new TerserPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      minify: false,
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "HeaderApp",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./HeaderApp": "./src/index.js",
      },
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

and the vite.config.js in other app is:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: "vue-app",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        header: "HeaderApp@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

I've also utilized the remote header component inside of main.js in vue-app as follows:

```
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
import "./style.css";
import App from "./App.vue";

import("header/HeaderApp").then((HeaderAppModule) => {
  console.log("header app", HeaderAppModule);
  const HeaderApp = HeaderAppModule.default;
  const headerapp = new HeaderApp();
  headerapp.render(["home"]);
});

const app = createApp(App);
app.mount("#app");
```

But, when run the command: `npm run serve`, the following error appears at browser:
`x00__virtual:__federation__:48 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'HeaderApp@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js' at __x00__virtual:__federation__:48:37 (`.
How can solve this problem?